# Status bar removal SWRevealController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), and I have the status bar visible on the main view controller, but it gets hidden when I tap the side menu.

The side menu will come out from the left, and it will also shift the main view controller's title bar up when the status bar is removed. When I tap the menu button again, the title bar comes back down when the status bar is added, and the title bar will then cover my content on the top of my view.

Can anyone look at this SWRevealController and give me any insight on how to stop it from removing the status bar? I think that would stop it from causing the title bar to bounce back down over my content. Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: 
It is called in the view controller in the following code:

```
if revealViewController() != nil {
menuButton.target = revealViewController()
menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 275
revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 160
view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

The framework itself is in the repo that I linked above.

Comment: Welcome! Could you show us the code you are working on, and where it is failing?

Comment: edited my original post